# Check if decimal value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal

I would like to check if the decimal number is NULL or it has some value, since the value is assigned from database in class object:

```
public decimal myDecimal{ get; set; }
```

and then I have

```
myDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(rdrSelect[23].ToString());
```

I am trying:

```
if (rdrSelect[23] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        myDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(rdrSelect[23].ToString());
                    }
```

But I am getting this:

> the result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type
>   'decimal' is never equal to null

How can I check if that decimal number has some value?

Comment: `Decimal` is a value type. It can never be null. If your column in your db is nullable, then it should be represented by a `Decimal?` (which is the short hand for `System.Nullable<Decimal>`

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal` will fail if `rdrSelect[23]` is null from the database.

Comment: So did you read the error message.  It seems rather clear.  `decimal ` can't ever be null, it will always have a value.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A decimal will always have some default value. If you need to have a [nullable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) decimal, you can use `decimal?`. Then you can do `myDecimal.HasValue`

Answer (score 15):

you can use this code

```
if (DecimalVariable.Equals(null))  
{
   //something statements
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution for a non-nullable type decimal.

Comment: @DanielZA Tanx dear friend

Answer (score 7):

`decimal` is a [*`value type`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) in .NET. And value types can't be `null`. But if you use [*`nullable type`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) for your `decimal`, then you can check your `decimal` is `null` or not. Like `myDecimal?`

> Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A nullable
> type can represent the normal range of values for its underlying value
> type, plus an additional **null** value.

```
if (myDecimal.HasValue)
```

But I think in your database, if this column contains nullable values, then it **shouldn't** be type of `decimal`.

Answer (score 2):

I've ran across this problem recently while trying to retrieve a null decimal from a `DataTable` object from db and I haven't seen this answer here. I find this easier and shorter:

```
var value = rdrSelect.Field<decimal?>("ColumnName") ?? 0;
```

This was useful in my case since i didn't have a nullable decimal in the model, but needed a quick check against one. If the db value happens to be null, it'll just assign the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are reading from a data row, what you want is:

```
if ( !rdrSelect.IsNull(23) ) 
{ 
   //handle parsing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decimal is a value type, so if you wish to check whether it has a value other than the value it was initialised with (zero) you can use the condition myDecimal != default(decimal).

Otherwise you should possibly consider the use of a nullable (decimal?) type and the use a condition such as myNullableDecimal.HasValue

Answer (score 0):

If you're pulling this value directly from a SQL Database and the value is null in there, it will actually be the `DBNull` object rather than null. Either place a check prior to your conversion & use a default value in the event of `DBNull`, or replace your null check afterwards with a check on `rdrSelect[23]` for `DBNull`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a handy utility functions to handle values from DB in cases like these. 
Ex. Below is the function which gives you Nullable Decimal from object type.

```
    public static decimal? ToNullableDecimal(object val)
    {
        if (val is DBNull ||
            val == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (val is string &&
            ((string)val).Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return Convert.ToDecimal(val);
    }
```